# Creating a subsample using a weighted distribution

Tags: python, gaussian, weighted

I have two samples of cookies. Sample 1 has 51 cookies and sample 2 has 47 cookies.
They have different mass distributions, D1 and D2, and I have fit gaussians to them via python. The plot below shows the samples' mass distributions, as well as the weighted distribution which is defined as D2/D1.

I'm interested in creating a subsample of Sample 1, which takes into account the weighted distribution, to allow a more fair comparison between the two samples due to their varying masses. The Gaussians that I've fit have 1000 points in them, and thus the weighted distribution is a different size than the sample arrays.

How would one go about doing this in python?

[Image of mass distributions of two samples of cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh251.png)

Comment: Is this using native Python, or are you using libraries such as numpy, scipy or pandas etc...?

Comment: I dont use pandas, but i do use numpy and scipy. I fit the Gaussians using Model from "lmfit"

Comment: Have you looked at [numpy.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and using `p` to provide weights?

Comment: One issue is that Gaussians I've fit have 1000 points, so the weighted distribution is a different size than the sample arrays (51 and 47).  Not sure the appropriate way to account for this

Comment: Right... make sure to [edit] your question with that necessary information...